# Can not install Google eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, google-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install Google eclipse plugin on eclipse 3.5 - Galileo.

But it gives me following error.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2009-09-29 11:55:29.563
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at 
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:380)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:641)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:93)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:89)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.load(CompositeArtifactRepository.java:426)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.addChild(CompositeArtifactRepository.java:159)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.<init>(CompositeArtifactRepository.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:98)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:669)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:617)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:93)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.loadRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:89)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.DownloadManager.fetch(DownloadManager.java:107)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.DownloadManager.start(DownloadManager.java:97)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect.completePhase(Collect.java:73)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:195)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:78)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:44)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:54)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningUtil.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningUtil.java:389)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProfileModificationOperation.doExecute(ProfileModificationOperation.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningOperation.execute(ProvisioningOperation.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.ProvisioningOperationRunner$1.run(ProvisioningOperationRunner.java:94)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 1000 2009-09-29 11:55:29.610
!MESSAGE No repository found at 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.ui,3.4.1.v20090901_r351
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.0.300.v200909170800
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt,3.5.1.v200909170800
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core,3.3.201.R35x_v20090818-0235
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core,1.0.201.R35x_v20090818-0225
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt,1.0.201.R35x_v20090825-1530
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool,1.0.100.v_972_R35x
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.5.1.v_972_R35x
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,3.4.1.v20090811_r351
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user,3.5.1.r351_v20090821-0800
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit,3.5.1.r351_v20090708-0800
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.5.1.r351_v20090821-0800
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui,3.3.201.R35x_v20090826-0905
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.views.log,1.0.100.v20090731
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.junit4,4.5.0.v20090824
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cvs,1.1.101.R35x_v20090811-7E79FEd9KKF5H2YDWFLLBL01A16
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.cvs_root,1.1.101.R35x_v20090811-7E79FEd9KKF5H2YDWFLLBL01A16
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jdt,3.5.1.r351_v20090810-0600-7r88FEoFI0WTo6Az-1qFRHm37ChJ
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.jdt_root,3.5.1.r351_v20090810-0600-7r88FEoFI0WTo6Az-1qFRHm37ChJ
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.build,3.5.1.R35x_20090820
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2009-09-29 11:57:20.517
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.core,3.5.100.v20090821
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse foundation has been having server issues for the last few days since releasing 3.5.1.  See [bug 289408](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=289408), [bug 290760](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290760), and [bug 290723](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290723).  This is probably the source of your problems.

Comment: Overview of what went wrong is on the webmaster's blog: http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/eclipsewebmaster/2009/09/30/wow-what-a-painful-release-this-was-is/